# Is it possible to create a trigger for emails that send from workflows?

Tags: salesforce

I would like to change emails sent from workflows to be sent to an additional recipient, the manager of the current User. I can possibly do this by rebuilding all my workflows, but I'm wondering is there any way to do it in a Trigger on the EmailMessage object so that this will work for every email sent. I have tried to do this, but it seems that emails sent from workflows don't go through this object.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to building a trigger you can do a search and replace in eclipse to add the recipient.

You'd start with this

```
<alerts>
  ...
  <recipients>
    <field>Engineer_s_Email__c</field>
    <type>email</type>
  </recipients>
  <recipients>
    <recipient>jason.bourne@salesforce.com</recipient>
    <type>user</type>
  </recipients>
  ...
</alerts>
```

Then do a file search and replace (ctrl-h).  Search for `</alerts>` and replace with `<recipients><recipient>manager.john@salesforce.com</recipient><type>user</type></recipients></alerts>`.  Which would give you:

```
<alerts>
  ...
  <recipients>
    <field>Engineer_s_Email__c</field>
    <type>email</type>
  </recipients>
  <recipients>
    <recipient>jason.bourne@salesforce.com</recipient>
    <type>user</type>
  </recipients>
  ...
<recipients><recipient>manager.john@salesforce.com</recipient><type>user</type></recipients></alerts></alerts>
```

Click okay and it'll add the manager as a recipient to all the workflow email alerts.

If you want to get fancy, use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

The EmailMessage object is directly related to Cases; it's found in Setup | Cases | Email Messages (as described in the [Winter 10 Release Notes](http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter10_release_notes.pdf)). It is used for inbound emails (typically with the Email-to-Case feature). Because of this I believe it is not involved in the outbound Email Alerts functionality associated with Workflows.

Unfortunately, the only way I know of to add an additional recipient to all Workflows is to modify each Workflow rule.